# How to set column name using setString() hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
<sql-query name="sql">
   select :COLUMN_NAME from table.
</sql-query>
```

I want to set `COLUMN_NAME` using

```
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("sql")
                .setString("COLUMN_NAME", "id");
```

I got a wrong result when I use this code (I know where I fail). Is there any way to set `COLUMN_NAME` using `getNamedQuery()` and `setString()`.

Comment: `"got a wrong result"` where it went wrong please post the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setParameter` method?

```
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("sql")
                .setParameter("COLUMN_NAME", "id");
```

Further [info](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: No it doesn't work. it seems COLUMN_NAME as String like select "COLUMN_NAME" from table so it returns COLUMN_NAME word.

Comment: So you want to change the name of the column dynamically, why?

Comment: Because table has columns like col1 col2 col3 ... col100. I only want to use 3 columns but these 3 colums can be col5 col10 col30 or col7 col8 col9 or any other option so I want to change sql column name dynamically and call sql like "select col1, col5, col99 from table"

Answer (score 0):

You must add `<return-scalar column="name_first" type="string" />` to get specific column. like

```
    <sql-query name="sql">
       <return-scalar column="COLUMN_NAME" type="java.lang.String" />
       select :COLUMN_NAME from table.
    </sql-query>
```

Or you can use `setResultTransformer` method if you had created a `bean` class for that table.

Comment: it return org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Invalid column name but column name is true

Comment: You will have to map your table column in your `.hbm` file or through `annotations`

Comment: After reading your other comment `I only want to use 3 columns but these 3...` I have a question, will the Data Type of these column will be same, or it will change like sometime it will be `Integer` sometime `Date` or something.